Help on Abaqus Mesh Partition
Hello everyone,
I'm currently working on a project involving the simulation of a balloon(?) using Abaqus. I am facing some issues with partitioning the mesh, specifically at the bottom part of the balloon/sac. (the pict I attached is actually a solid)
I've tried all available partition methods (datum planes, sketch-based partitions, and feature-based partitions), but I can't seem to get a well-defined partition. The mesh doesn't seem to partition properly.
I have tried refining the mesh and adjusting the partitioning methods, but without success.
Any advice or insights guys?
Thank you in advance for your help!
